# How can I make bot reply to an audio message?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

How can I make **aiogram bot** reply to an audio message?
I have already tried this:

```
if message.Audio.duration <= 60:
    await message.reply("message")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.VOICE | types.ContentTypes.AUDIO)
async def audio_message_handler(msg: types.Message):
    if msg.content_type == "voice":
        await msg.reply("Voice message")
    elif msg.content_type == "audio":
        await msg.reply("Audio message")
```